# Glassfish, OSGi web application bundle (WAB) and virtual servers

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, osgi, glassfish-4

After all tests with WAB it seems that GF(4) can work only with virtual server "server" (default virtual server) and ignores all other virtual servers. So my question - has anyone succeeded in setting different virtual servers for wab\eab in one domain with glassfish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer! As I understand the answer is only in one place in entire internet. It's here: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-11700

> This is an initial version of the fix which only supports one virtual
>   server to be set while deploying a WAB. Like Web-ContextPath, user has
>   to supply this information in MANIFEST.MF of the WAB. The header name
>   is "Virtual-Servers." When the header is absent or the header name is
>   empty, we only deploy to default virtual server. If user tries to set
>   multiple virtual server in the manifest header Virtual-Servers, a
>   runtime exception is raised at this point of time indicating that we
>   don't yet support multiple virtual servers. We will fix it when I have
>   some more time.